# Python3.3 HTML Client TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Tags: python, html, string, client

```
import socket

# Set up a TCP/IP socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Connect as client to a selected server
# on a specified port
s.connect(("www.wellho.net",80))

# Protocol exchange - sends and receives
s.send("GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n")
while True:
        resp = s.recv(1024)
        if resp == "": break
        print(resp,)

# Close the connection when completed
s.close()
print("\ndone")
```

Error:

```
cg0546wq@smaug:~/Desktop/440$ python3 HTTPclient.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "HTTPclient.py", line 11, in <module>
    s.send("GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n")
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

Can NOT use

- `urllib.request.urlopen`
- `urllib2.urlopen`
- `http`
- `http.client`
- `httplib`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sockets can only accept *bytes*, while you are trying to send it a Unicode string instead.

Encode your strings to bytes:

```
s.send("GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n".encode('ascii'))
```

or give it a bytes literal (a string literal starting with a `b` prefix):

```
s.send(b"GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n")
```

Take into account that data you *receive* will also be `bytes` values; you cannot just compare those to `''`. Just test for an *empty* response, and you probably want to decode the response to `str` when printing:

```
while True:
    resp = s.recv(1024)
    if not resp: break
    print(resp.decode('ascii'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import socket

# Set up a TCP/IP socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Connect as client to a selected server
# on a specified port
s.connect(("www.google.com",80))

# Protocol exchange - sends and receives
s.send(b"GET /index.html HTTP/1.0\n\n")
while True:
        resp = s.recv(1024)
        if resp == b'': break
        print(resp,)

# Close the connection when completed
s.close()
print("\ndone")
```