# TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API

Tags: string, python-3.x, buffer

There's this python script (found [here](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/02/my-extravagant-zsh-prompt/#my-right-prompt-battery-capacity)) that i'm using to show my laptop's battery percentage as part of my `$PROMPT`. It works a charm for `python` (aka version 2). But it doesn't work with `python3`. This is a problem because i am using pyenv and pyenv-virtualenv to work on projects and sometimes `python` command points to a 3+ version. That produces these errors in the terminal when the battery script is evaluated:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                             
  File "/usr/local/bin/batcharge.py", line 9, in <module>
    o_max = [l for l in output.splitlines() if 'MaxCapacity' in l][0]
  File "/usr/local/bin/batcharge.py", line 9, in <listcomp>
    o_max = [l for l in output.splitlines() if 'MaxCapacity' in l][0]
TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API
```

Here is the file, it's pretty short if someone can help identify what is going on.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=UTF-8

import math, subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(["ioreg", "-rc", "AppleSmartBattery"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = p.communicate()[0]

o_max = [l for l in output.splitlines() if 'MaxCapacity' in l][0]
o_cur = [l for l in output.splitlines() if 'CurrentCapacity' in l][0]

b_max = float(o_max.rpartition('=')[-1].strip())
b_cur = float(o_cur.rpartition('=')[-1].strip())

charge = b_cur / b_max
charge_threshold = int(math.ceil(10 * charge))

# Output

total_slots, slots = 10, []
filled = int(math.ceil(charge_threshold * (total_slots / 10.0))) * u'▸'
empty = (total_slots - len(filled)) * u'▹'

out = (filled + empty).encode('utf-8')
import sys

color_green = '%{[32m%}'
color_yellow = '%{[1;33m%}'
color_red = '%{[31m%}'
color_reset = '%{[00m%}'
color_out = (
    color_green if len(filled) > 6
    else color_yellow if len(filled) > 3
    else color_red
)

out = color_out + out + color_reset
sys.stdout.write(out)
```

Obviously, `python3` is choking on something in the list comprehension, yet I can't figure out what.

According to shell, this is what is returned by output.splitlines() before the program crashes:

```
[b'+-o AppleSmartBattery  <class AppleSmartBattery, id 0x1000001dc, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (1 ms), retain 6>', b'    {', b'      "ExternalConnected" = Yes', b'      "TimeRemaining" = 0', b'      "InstantTimeToEmpty" = 65535', b'      "ExternalChargeCapable" = Yes', b'      "FullPathUpdated" = 1431620425', b'      "CellVoltage" = (4148,4147,4147,0)', b'      "Voltage" = 12442', b'      "BatteryInvalidWakeSeconds" = 30', b'      "AdapterInfo" = 0', b'      "MaxCapacity" = 5886', b'      "PermanentFailureStatus" = 0', b'      "Manufacturer" = "SMP"', b'      "Location" = 0', b'      "CurrentCapacity" = 5727', b'      "LegacyBatteryInfo" = {"Amperage"=0,"Flags"=5,"Capacity"=5886,"Current"=5727,"Voltage"=12442,"Cycle Count"=539}', b'      "FirmwareSerialNumber" = 27251', b'      "BatteryInstalled" = Yes', b'      "PackReserve" = 200', b'      "CycleCount" = 539', b'      "DesignCapacity" = 6900', b'      "OperationStatus" = 58435', b'      "ManufactureDate" = 15675', b'      "AvgTimeToFull" = 65535', b'      "BatterySerialNumber" = "W0040P2ABBWZA"', b'      "BootPathUpdated" = 1430956311', b'      "PostDischargeWaitSeconds" = 120', b'      "Temperature" = 3036', b'      "UserVisiblePathUpdated" = 1431620485', b'      "InstantAmperage" = 0', b'      "ManufacturerData" = <000000000201000a01580000034b3138033030410341544c00130000>', b'      "MaxErr" = 1', b'      "FullyCharged" = Yes', b'      "DeviceName" = "bq20z451"', b'      "IOGeneralInterest" = "IOCommand is not serializable"', b'      "Amperage" = 0', b'      "IsCharging" = No', b'      "DesignCycleCount9C" = 1000', b'      "PostChargeWaitSeconds" = 120', b'      "AvgTimeToEmpty" = 65535', b'    }', b'    ', b'']
```

I have [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471158/typeerror-str-does-not-support-the-buffer-interface) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26945613/str-does-not-support-the-buffer-interface-python3-from-python2) [pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26537592/python3-3-html-client-typeerror-str-does-not-support-the-buffer-interface) here that have the same error and the fixes that are suggested do not work for me.

Namely, `bytes(l, 'utf-8')` and `l.encode('utf-8')` do not work. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, prepend the strings in the optional predicate of the list comprehension with `b` to encode them as `bytes` instead of strings. As such, lines 9 and 10 become:

```
o_max = [l for l in output.splitlines() if b'MaxCapacity' in l][0]
o_cur = [l for l in output.splitlines() if b'CurrentCapacity' in l][0]
```

Although I correctly realized there was an issue with the list comprehension, i wasn't able to figure out what; the answer was shamefully hiding in plain sight. I kept trying to convert what was being stored in `l` instead of paying attention to the string in the code. Leaving this here in hopes of helping others.

Comment: The alternative would be to add the `universal_newlines=True` argument to the `subprocess.Popen()` call.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the entire file for anyone who was caught off guard with the removal of Python 2 from the Mac OS.  These edits work in Mac OS Monterey 12.5:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=UTF-8

import math, subprocess
# Fix: next three corrections from the following website:
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30245594/typeerror-type-str-doesnt-support-the-buffer-api
#p = subprocess.Popen(["ioreg", "-rc", "AppleSmartBattery"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p = subprocess.Popen(["ioreg", "-rc", "AppleSmartBattery"], universal_newlines=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = p.communicate()[0]

o_max = [l for l in output.splitlines() if 'MaxCapacity' in l][0]
#o_max = [l for l in output.splitlines() if b'MaxCapacity' in l][0] # correction ignored in lieu of above correction
o_cur = [l for l in output.splitlines() if 'CurrentCapacity' in l][0]
#o_cur = [l for l in output.splitlines() if b'CurrentCapacity' in l][0] # correction ignored in lieu of above correction

b_max = float(o_max.rpartition('=')[-1].strip())
b_cur = float(o_cur.rpartition('=')[-1].strip())

charge = b_cur / b_max
charge_threshold = int(math.ceil(10 * charge))

# Output

total_slots, slots = 10, []
# Fix: ran '2to3 batcharge.py' in Terminal and made suggested corrections.
# 2to3 program will backup old file and write new one with -w: i.e. '2to3 -w batcharge.py'
#filled = int(math.ceil(charge_threshold * (total_slots / 10.0))) * u'▸'
filled = int(math.ceil(charge_threshold * (total_slots / 10.0))) * '▸'
#empty = (total_slots - len(filled)) * u'▹'
empty = (total_slots - len(filled)) * '▹'

# Fix: removed encoding to eliminate this error:
# out = color_out + out + color_reset TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str
#out = (filled + empty).encode('utf-8')
out = filled + empty
import sys

color_green = '%{[32m%}'
color_yellow = '%{[1;33m%}'
color_red = '%{[31m%}'
color_reset = '%{[00m%}'
color_out = (
    color_green if len(filled) > 6
    else color_yellow if len(filled) > 4
    else color_red
)

out = color_out + out + color_reset
sys.stdout.write(out)
```